# wp_editor content in plugin options page

Tags: plugins, database, options

Hi I'm writing a plugin it involves the site builder / user adding content via wp_editor this content is then saved and submitted via a submit_button.

I've wrapped the editor in form action = "options.php"

Is this the best way to save the content as the content may be a whole screen of content.

I need the content from the editor to go via the submit_button.

Is it better to save the content to a newly created table via save post, but how would I connect that via submit_button

Thanks

Here's the code I'm experimenting with.

```
 $settings = array(
'quicktags' => array('buttons' => 'em,strong,link',),
'text_area_name'=>'addfloor',//name you want for the textarea
'quicktags' => true,
'tinymce' => true
 );
  $content="<div id='content'>

 //Add your floor here

 </div>";
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="options.php">
 <?php
 settings_fields( 'settings-group' );
 do_settings_sections( 'settings-group' );
  $addfloor = "<div id='content'>".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'addfloor',         true)."</div>";

 wp_editor( $addfloor, 'addfloor', $settings);

 function save_wp_editor_fields(){
 global $post;
 update_post_meta($post->ID, 'addfloor', $_POST['addfloor']);

  }
 add_action( 'save_post', 'save_wp_editor_fields' );

 submit_button( 'Save Floor!' );?>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hi It's just regarding the best way to save a potentially large amount of content via options.php or whether it should be saved as a post in it's own created table.

Comment: I need the content to be saved via submit button either way and this hooks in with using form action="options.php" If there is a large amount of content is get options update options suitable? Or is there a more suitable way? Thanks:-)

Comment: Code added above

Comment: http://omfgitsnater.com/2012/11/using-the-wordpress-editor-in-your-own-plugins-and-themes/ Looks like a potential solution to the same problem